# Custom Button in Android not saving state

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I have created a custom Button as follows.

file : buttoncontrol.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/greendot"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/reddot" />
</selector>
```

in the layout file.. I have used

```
    <Button
     ...
        android:background="@drawable/buttoncontrol"></Button>
```

When I try to run the program the layout shows the button with reddot (expected result). When I press the button, it turns green until I release the keypress. How can I make this green until the next click. More a toggle behaviour.

I have tried the same xml file in a toggle button as well. Same result.

Apart from this (for testing), I have also tried adding the following code in activity as well. Still not getting the desired result. (which is saving the state)

```
...under onClick of  Button/ToggleButton
buttonControl.setPressed(true);
```

Any suggestions? My preference is to avoid programatically controlling the state. i.e. I can always keep these images and use buttonContol.setBackgroundDrawable for the buttons

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made ToggleButton work by changing android:state_pressed="true" to android:state_checked="true" .

But the question still remains for Button. How to make button do a similar activity? Particularly when there are more than 2 states.

Answer (score 0):

A standard Button has no notion of persistent state.  You must create a custom implementation of Button that tracks the various states.  Sorry, but there's no way around it.